# What is the difference between client HTTP request and server HTTP request in Golang's "net/http"

Tags: http, go

I have seen people use `NewRequest()` method of the "net/http" package for testing APIs. Why not use the `NewRequest()` method from "net/http/httptesting"? What's the difference? Documentation advises [the following](https://golang.org/src/net/http/httptest/httptest.go#L39):

```
// To generate a client HTTP request instead of a server request, see
// the NewRequest function in the net/http package.
```

What would be the difference in handling cookies, for example? Both seem to be very similar.

Comment: The `Request` field and method documentation call out the difference between client use and server use.  [httptest.NewRequest](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#NewRequest) initializes a request as if it had been received on the server.  [http.NewRequest](https://godoc.org/net/http#NewRequest) initializes a request for client use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: they're the same type, used a bit differently for two use cases and initialized differently to serve these use cases

---

The difference is only in usage - they are the same type `http.Request`. `http.NewRequest` is used for the more "production" use case which is client - "create a new request to send to the server". When writing HTTP servers, it's occasionally useful to create requests for testing, which is what `httptest.NewRequest` does. The doc of `http.NewRequest` is helpful here:

> NewRequest returns a Request suitable for use with Client.Do or
>   Transport.RoundTrip. To create a request for use with testing a Server
>   Handler, either use the NewRequest function in the net/http/httptest
>   package, use ReadRequest, or manually update the Request fields. See
>   the Request type's documentation for the difference between inbound
>   and outbound request fields.

If you check the docs of the [http.Request type](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request), you'll find things like:

```
// URL specifies either the URI being requested (for server
// requests) or the URL to access (for client requests).
//
// For server requests, the URL is parsed from the URI
// supplied on the Request-Line as stored in RequestURI.  For
// most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be
// empty. (See RFC 7230, Section 5.3)
//
// For client requests, the URL's Host specifies the server to
// connect to, while the Request's Host field optionally
// specifies the Host header value to send in the HTTP
// request.
URL *url.URL
```

Note the "For client requests" vs. "For server requests".

If you see a place that doesn't use `httptest.NewRequest` it could be because:

1. They're not aware of it
2. Or they need more careful fine-tuning that `http.NewRequest` doesn't provide